# How to pass a MouseEventArgs with correct properties into event handlers?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, derived-class, flowlayoutpanel, eventargs

I have a program which has a *FlowLayoutPanel* inside its Form. I'm coding on the *FlowLayoutPanel*'s *MouseMove* event and everything works fine; except that it doesn't fire the *MouseMove* event while the cursor moves on its scroll bar.

I searched the web and found the following approach which uses a derived class from *FlowLayoutPanel* and then overrides its *WndProc* method:

```
    class FlowLayoutPanelEx : FlowLayoutPanel
    {
        const int WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0x00A0;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE)
            {
                base.OnMouseMove(null);
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

I'm having problem with raising (or calling) the *base.OnMouseMove()*. It requires a *MouseEventArgs* object to be passed in as parameter. I need to pass the correct *MouseEventArgs* because my event handler relies on it, but I don't know how to set/where to get the right properties (Buttons, X, Y, etc.) to pass the correct *MouseMoveEvent*.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the mouse moving across the scrollbar by intercepting the WM_NCMOUSEMOVE message.  Like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0xA0) {  // WM_NCMOUSEMOVE.
        var pos = this.PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()));
        var evt = new MouseEventArgs(Control.MouseButtons, 0, pos.X, pos.Y, 0);
        OnMouseMove(evt);
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: There are two problems with the code you provided:

First, the X and Y values are positions of the pointer on the whole screen and not on user control. I need the coordinate of the pointer on user control only, and I can't do operations on the X and Y passed in the event handler.

Second, I need the MouseButtons property.

BTW, what does OnNcMouseMove do?

Comment: Updates with translation of screen to window coords. OnNcMouseMove would be the normal recipient of this message.

Comment: there is no OnNcMouseMove method!
Both OnNcMouseMove and base.OnNcMouseMove results in these errors: "'System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel' does not contain a definition for 'OnNcMouseMove'", "The name 'OnNcMouseMove' does not exist in the current context".